# Current git branch not displayed in Eclipse package explorer

Tags: eclipse, git-branch

I have checked the boxes **"Git Repository Objects"** and **"Git Resources"** in *Preferences>General>Appearance>Label Decorations*. Also in *Preferences>Version Control (Team)>Git>Label Decorations>Text Decorations* I have **"{dirty:>} {name} [{repository }{branch}{ branch_status}]"** under Projects.

Is there any other setting I need to set? This is in the original workspace where the project was created, in another Eclipse instance with a different workspace the branch is displayed as it should.

Comment: Is the repository clone that the project is located within also known by the Git Repositories View?

Comment: Maybe your project is copy and not the Git working tree. Please tell your project location (_Project > Properties: Resource_) and the location of your Git repository.

Comment: Sorry, Im new to git, so I dont understand these questions, to describe what I did: Eclipse project A was added to github as a repository, then changes were made to that project within the same Eclipse workspace and a new branch added. In another Eclipse instance B the repository has been added as a project and is showing the branch it is currently on. But in Eclipse A it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using STS 4(backed by Eclipse). I deleted ProjectManager(project) from STS 4 (but not from disk),

When I had a warning of "contains resources that are not in sync with", I refreshed the project with F5 in the (package)Explorer.

Then I imported the project again and I'm seeing the branch name as shown below.

[image: Shown branch name after project delete and import]